# access a char pointer in a struct C++ and allocate memory

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, char, malloc

I want to receive bytes into conbuf.buffer. either of test 1 or test2 is ok. I am not seeing any value in printf statement. Am I passing in the pointer correctly? How do I allocate memory to a char pointer inside a struct.

```
typedef struct cBuf
{
    int size;
    char *buffer;
} cbuf;

class A
{
    cbuf conbuf;
    void test();
}

void A::test()
{
    int buffersize = 20;
    char buf[buffersize];

    conbuf.buffer = (char *)malloc(buffersize * sizeof(char *));

    // test 1
    int n = socket.receivebytes(conbuf.buffer, buffersize);

    // test 2
    //int n = socket.receivebytes(buf, buffersize);
    //strcpy(conbuf.buffer, buf);

    printf("conbuf.buffer %s \n", conbuf.buffer);
}
```

Comment: -1: Can you post some code that actually compiles?

Comment: What exact data is being sent over the socket?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of manual memory allocation.

Comment: @kevin: This is part of another big project. I took out the lines that I use the buffer.

The data received is some array of chars. I have to do manual memory alloc.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
 conbuf.buffer = (char *)malloc(buffersize * sizeof(char *));
```

should be

```
  conbuf.buf = (char *)malloc(buffersize * sizeof(char)); //allocate space for char not pointer to char.  Your struct only has buf member not "buffer"
```

Comment: sizeof(char*) is always greater than on equal to sizeof(char).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
conbuf.buffer = (char *)calloc(  (buffersize * sizeof(char))+1,1);
```

since printf requires last char of string to be null terminated, this ensures it. But data received from network may already contain NUL in the middle. So instead of using printf you should use fwrite:

```
fwrite(conbuf.buffer,buffersize , STDOUT);
```

I'd suggest you to redirect it in a file and do a hex dump to see the output.

Comment: Thanks AgA! but in test 1, conbuf.buffer is null whereas in test 2, buf in receivebytes is not null. So I am wondering if it is due to incorrect pointer somewhere? Is my memory allocation correct? I changed it to the one you mentioned..

Comment: Unless you give the code I can't comment since your statement is confusing. calloc will never return null unless all memory is exhausted. Also buffersize should be declared as const int since for declaring array the size should be in cost in most C++ implementations.